# DNS resolution fails after wakeup from standby (Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: suspend, dns, 16.10

Since I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 DNS resolution stopped working every time the computer wakes up from standby. Pinging IP addresses directly works without a problem. So the issue seems to be DNS related. To solve it I have to reboot the computer (logout and login doesn't solve it).

Any idea how to investigate this issue further?

Comment: Same here. For me, DNS resolution doesn't work at all (i.e. also not after booting), whereas ping to 8.8.8.8 works fine. The DNS shown under "Connection Information" is the same as the one shown on another computer where the connection through the same modem works fine.

Comment: Same here. I joined https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1618839 though it was reported for xenial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had the same issue with Ubuntu 16.10 on MacbookPro.

Fixed it by disabling dnsmasq in network manager by commenting out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Comment: This fixed my issue on 16.04. I only recently saw the issue on 16.04, whereas the intial bulk of reports came in around October for 16.10, so perhaps 16.04 just received the same buggy update to network manager or dnsmasq.  Here's the [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1631241) with some discussion.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found is [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340142) thread where users are complaining for `dnsmasq` and advising to restart it. I've tried (`sudo service dnsmasq restart`) and it helped. So I configured this restarting to cron job every minute as temporary solution.

Comment: I don't have dnsmasq installed so that this solution  doesn't work for me.