# Ubuntu 16.10 recurring DNS problem

Tags: dns, 16.10

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.10 on my dual booted system. My net connection seemed fine until one day, only selected websites could be open. The error was "DNS not resolved" on Chromium and similar on Firefox. 
Although a ping with IP address of all blocked websites was working fine.
One of two steps helps me to resolve the problem temporarily:
1. Disconnecting and connecting to my network.
2. System Restart.

Steps I tried to resolve it permanently:
1. Changed the ISP DNS to OpenDNS and GoogleDNS in my router settings. None have resolved the problem.

**Edit 2:**

I tried commenting out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` as given here: [DNS resolution fails after wakeup from standby (Ubuntu 16.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837575/dns-resolution-fails-after-wakeup-from-standby-ubuntu-16-10?rq=1)
It didn't work either. However, I have noticed while reconnecting to the wifi network, any website can be loaded.

Comment: Do you have changed only the router DNS? Have you tried to change your config in network manager also?

Comment: check your /etc/resolv.conf what do you see in?