# DNS queries fail, while IP addresses work, after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 in VirtualBox

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, dns, 17.04

DNS queries fail, while IP addresses work, after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 in VirtualBox. Applied updates to 16.10 before upgrading to 17.04.

i.e. sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
except I did the update and upgrade via gui.

Comment: Can you post the exact command and address you are using to try these DNS queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DNS resolution fails after wakeup from standby (Ubuntu 16.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837575/dns-resolution-fails-after-wakeup-from-standby-ubuntu-16-10)

Comment: ping 156.151.59.35 works, while

ping www.sun.com

fails on the upgraded 17.04, but works everywhere else.

I restarted the 17.04 system several times but this did not help.

Comment: ping www.sun.com fails

Comment: Post `cat /etc/resolv.conf` from host and VM (presuming VM is also *nix)

Comment: On Host: cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.name

Comment: On 17.04 /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN nameserver 127.0.1.53 search domain.name –
nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: copy paste did not work, so I transcribed manually, hoping I did not make any errors. Double checking..... 17.04 used nameserver 127.0.0.53 while 16.10 used 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Here is systemd-resolve --status on the 16.10 host:
systemd-resolve --status
Global
         DNS Servers: 127.0.1.1
          DNS Domain: domain.name
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (eno1)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
truncated -- too long by 700+ characters ... chopped some off in the middle.

Comment: Difference is apparent. 
On the 16.10 host systemd-resolve --status has the line:
Global
         DNS Servers: 127.0.1.1
          DNS Domain: domain.name

Comment: Whereas on the 17.04 system on a VirtualBox where DNS does not work, systemd-resolve --status has the line:
Link 2 (emp0s3)
Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNT/IPv6
LLMNR settings: yes
MulticastDNS settings: no
DNSSEC settings: allow-downgrade
DNSSEC supported: yes
DNS Servers: 10.0.2.3
DNS Domain: domain.name

Comment: On the 16.10 system that works, the DNS Servers: is in Global.
On the 17.04 system where DNS fails, the DNS Servers: is under Link 2 (enp0s3)

Comment: On the 17.04 system where DNS lookup fails, when I execute the command 'dig @10.0.2.3 www.sun.com' I get the correct IP address 156.151.59.35, whereas, when I execute the command 'dig www.sun.com' I get no ANSWER SECTION on the query.

Comment: Interesting development: After a long delay and several dig @10.0.2.3 www.sun.com commands, now, ping www.sun.com works on the upgraded 17.04 system; however any other dns name, such as www.mozilla.org fails, as before, with the same message (as before) Name or service not known.

Comment: When I execute dig @10.0.2.3 www.mozilla.org I get an IP address in the ANWSER SECTION and the address is correct and works. However, dig www.mozilla.org returns with no ANSWER SECTION and no IP address. cat /etc/resolv.conf nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf contains the uncommented line: 'nameserver 127.0.0.53' and systemd-resolve --status contains: 'DNS Servers: 10.0.2.3' under Link 2 (enp0s3) not under Global.

Comment: Slowly, more and more DNS names begin to work. Yahoo, google, but many others still do not resolve, like: Mozilla, ...
H'mm, interesting: "http://www.zerohedge.com/" worked, but
"http://www.silverdoctors.com" does not (note the missing /).

Comment: After ten minutes, Firefox can get to "http://SilverDoctors.com/".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading. Though I didn't investigate the issue too much thus have no deep undestanding of the root cause, in my env it was fixed by editing system config file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and adding the following entry to the global section: `dns=dnsmasq` .